# Creating a branch from issue in GitLab

Tags: gitlab, branching-and-merging, issue-tracking

I've just started using GitLab, and have created a set of issues, in order to keep an overview of what needs to be done for my application. I was wondering if it was possible to create a branch from these issues, such that the branch and issues are linked, similar as in jira and Stash from atlassian?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

If you create a branch with the name `<issue-number>-issue-description` and push that branch to gitlab, it will automatically be linked to that issue. For instance, if you have an issue with id `654` and you create a branch with name `654-some-feature` and push it to gitlab, it will be linked to issue `654`.

Gitlab will even ask you if you want to create a merge request and will automatically add `Closes #654` to the merge request description which will close `issue 654` when the merge request is accepted.

Also if you go to a given issue page on gitlab, you should see a `New Branch` button which will automatically create a branch with a name of the form `<issue-number>-issue-description`.

Comment: I was hoping to see a New Branch button, but either its not there or I can't find it. Do you know where it is placed?

Comment: never mind found the create new branch. It seems like Gitlab created a branch for me for the first issue, without realizing it myself.

Comment: Regarding the missing Create Branch button, see @Robert Echlin's answer.

Comment: @JonasN89 you should consider changing the accepted answer to Robert Echlin's answer because that exactly answers your question.

Comment: An observation: the "Create Pull Request for Issue" Button is only visible once an Issue is Non-Confidential.

Comment: Can one branch be linked to more than one issue in a case where the branch addresses those issues?

Answer (score 51):

On the Issue screen, you see a green button labeled "Create merge request", with a down-arrow to its right.

That's not a button, that's a drop down list of buttons.

- Click on the down arrow
- Choose "Create branch"
- Click on "Create branch"
- A branch is created from the issue number, plus the title of the branch

  - For example, my issue #2, with title "Test repoSearch with no repos"
    will have a branch called:
  - 2-test-reposearch-with-no-repos
  - Notice that it changes case to all-lower-case

Comment: That button is not displayed for me. Does it have to do with my branch structure (Git Flow) or because it is a fork of a different project?

Comment: Is it posible for GitLab to recognise other name format? For instance, create a branch called `feature/2` by default instead of `2-the-title`. And, would they be linked by GitLab? That would be a must feature IMHO.

Comment: @molerat I'm having the issue where it's not showing for me either in the current project. In one project, I have 2 buttons. Show Activity and Create Merge Request. In the other, I only have Show Activity

Comment: same here, on some issues the button is displayed while not in others; cannot understand which criteria gitlab uses to show it or not

Comment: The repository must not be empty and the 'repository' feature should be enabled in the project settings (Settings > General > Visibility, project features, permissions).

Tested on Gitlab 13.8.7 / Docker.

Comment: See this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69262304/gitlab-create-branch-and-merge-request-from-issue/69979349#69979349) regarding the Merge Request button not displaying on the Issue screen.

Comment: @RogerCampanera it seems the only option for Gitlab is ```feature/2-<some-branch>``` then when you do a merge request add ```#2``` in the comment box and it will link then, you could just do a MR right from the start to link it. From what I can tell on Gitbhub you can link pull-request to ```feature/2-<some-branch>``` but doesn't have the autolinking of ```2-<some-branch>``` like GitLab

Comment: My issue was due to my project being a fork of another repo. I had to follow the recommendation from @Jubilsoft-Scott above to "Remove Project Fork Relationship" and the issue was resolved. I could then create a branch (and MR) from the issue as desired.

Answer (score 2):

TLDR: **do a merge request add `#2` in the title and/or in the comment box and/or the commit message and it will link the issue to the branch and commit, you could just do a MR right from the start to link it.**

It seems the only option for *Gitlab* is name your branch following this format: `<issue-number-some-branch>` like `2-bad-ai` this will autolink the branch to the issue.

However, I organize my branches so they live nicely in the .git/ref/heads folder structure like this `feature/2-<some-branch>` then when you **do a merge request add `#2` in the title and/or in the comment box and/or the commit message and it will link the issue to the branch and commit, you could just do a MR right from the start to link it.**

```
$ ls .git/refs/heads/; ls .git/refs/remotes/upstream/
2-bad-ai  dev  feature/  hotfix/  master  release/
2-bad-ai  dev  feature/  hotfix/  master  release/
```

I'd much rather have `feature/2-bad-ai` in the above output...

From what I can tell on *Github* you can link pull-request to `feature/2-<some-branch>` but doesn't have the autolinking of `2-<some-branch>` like GitLab

Answer (score 2):

2017:

> If you create a branch with the name `<issue-number>-issue-description` and push that branch to GitLab, it will automatically be linked to that issue.

This is now customizable, with [GitLab 15.6](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/11/22/gitlab-15-6-released/#configure-default-names-for-branches-created-from-issues) (November 2022):

> ### Configure default names for branches created from issues
>
> Define a custom template for naming branches created from issues. The previous setting `{issue ID}-{issue-title-hyphenated}` remains the default.
>
> To define a custom template for your project, go to **`Repository Settings > Branch defaults`**.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/15_6/configure_default_names_for_branches_created_from_issues.png -- Configure default names for branches created from issues]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/web_editor.html#create-a-new-branch-from-an-issue) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/21243).