# Gitlab - create branch and merge request from issue

Tags: gitlab

It used to be possible to create a branch from a gitlab issue, however this functionality is no longer there.

Does it need to be explicitly enabled somewhere?

Or is there a new way to create a branch from an issue?

Comment: AFAIK, this functionality is still there. Create the issue, select the issue, then choose _create merge request_.

Comment: The button is now labeled _Create Merge Request_ but if you click the arrow next to it you can choose to create both the branch and Merge Request or just the branch, and can customize the branch name.

Answer (score 5):

This one tripped me up as well!

Per the Gitlab user documentation,

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/web_editor.html#create-a-new-branch-from-an-issue

> The Create merge request button doesn’t display if:
>
> - A branch with the same name already exists.
> - A merge request already exists for this branch.
> - Your project has an active fork relationship.
>
> To make this button appear, one possible workaround is to remove your
> project’s fork relationship. After removal, the fork relationship
> cannot be restored. This project can no longer be able to receive or
> send merge requests to the source project, or other forks.

Otherwise, the button displays as indicated in the post by @Do_Nhu_Vy.

Comment: Do you have any idea why the button is hidden, if "your project has an active fork relationship"?

Comment: Gitlab web editor has completely changed since v15.  I am not sure that limitation still exists.  Review the (new) documentation at the link above for the current features and limitations.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is still exists. Let's see the sceenshot.

[image]